# React Redux connect() with Redux thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem when using Redux thunk with the `connect()` method from [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux). I have the following code:

```
function Component(props) {
    return (
        <button onClick={props.callback}>Click here</button>
    );
}

function actionCreator() {
    console.log('#1');
    return dispatch => console.log('#2'); // = thunk
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    callback: actionCreator
});
export const Container = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

When I render the `Container` component and click the button, only '#1' is being displayed in the console. So the 'thunk' doesn't get executed.

When I explicitly dispatch `actionCreator()`, it does work:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    callback: dispatch => dispatch(actionCreator())
});
```

[The Redux docs says this about mapDispatchToProps](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments):

> If an object is passed, each function inside it will be assumed to be
>   a Redux action creator

So why does mapDispatchToProps not `dispatch()` my `actionCreator()`? I'm new to React, so maybe I don't understand it right?

**Update**

When using `bindActionCreators()` from redux it does work:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        callback: actionCreator
    }, dispatch);
};
```

Is this the correct way to bind actioncreators with `connect()`?

Answer (score 7):

In your `mapDispatchToProps`, you are overriding the `dispatch` function by making it an argument of the function. Because you are doing the `dispatch => {function}`, the dispatch inside the function now refers to the argument you pass to the function – but you don't pass any argument to it.

```
callback: dispatch => dispatch(actionCreator())
           // ^ overrides ^
```

Change it to this, and it should work:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    callback: () => dispatch(actionCreator())
});
```

That way, when you call `callback()`, the `dispatch` refers to the passed `dispatch` function by `mapDispatchToProps`, and the action gets dispatched.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have included redux-thunk as middleware to my store. Your code doesn't work. It dispatches the actionCreator directly when the component mounts. When I then click the button I get the error "this.props.callback is not a function"

Comment: You're right, I found the real problem now. Change the `mapDispatchToProps` function to

`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ callback: () => dispatch(actionCreator()) });`

and it should work. I've edited my answer above to reflect that and explain why that is needed!

Comment: Thanks again. The problem is that `callback: dispatch => dispatch(actionCreator())` does work actually. But then the params passed into the `callback()` (from the component) will not be passed into `actionCreator()`. I've found that `bindActionCreators()` works for now.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `actionCreator` function returns a new function when it gets called. Remove the `return` in `actionCreator` will make it work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It doesn't work. Isn't returning a function the way of defining thunks?

Comment: @Jan-PaulKleemans Can you provide a jsfiddle? So I can help you out.

Comment: I've found that bindActionCreators() works for now. Thanks for your help.